# Why does process.argv[3] return something completely unexpected when it is '*'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a very simple calculator app:

```
if (process.argv[3]==='+') console.log(parseInt(process.argv[2]) + parseInt(process.argv[4]));
if (process.argv[3]==='-') console.log(parseInt(process.argv[2]) - parseInt(process.argv[4]));
if (process.argv[3]==='*') console.log(parseInt(process.argv[2]) * parseInt(process.argv[4]));
if (process.argv[3]==='/') console.log(parseInt(process.argv[2]) / parseInt(process.argv[4]));
console.log(process.argv[3])
```

2 + 2, 2 - 2, 2 / 2 all work as expected, but 2 * 2 will log out the name of the script.
Why does this happen? What is it about the multiplication sign?

Comment: Not an expert but maybe something to do with wild cards? Like when you want to list all js files and do "*.js"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `*` is a shell wildcard, It has a special meaning to the shell, which expands it before passing it to the node.

You have to pass it with `\*` like this or `"*"` or like this `'*'`.